# Combine 2 vector spaces commutatively

Tags: vector-spaces

I have a finite dimensional vector space $V$, and I want to create a "product" space
$$U = V \times V$$
similar to the Cartesian product, with elements like $(v_1, v_2)$, but I want it such that the product operation is commutative.  In other words,
$$(v_1, v_2) = (v_2, v_1)$$
I see that if I use the usual Cartesian product, the resulting vector space would have "wasted" half the space because it is symmetric about the diagonal.  Is it possible to not "waste" any space like this?  And would it be able to reduce the dimensionality of the target space?

Maybe another way to phrase this is to say I want a union of 2 (identical) vector spaces where the order is unimportant.

Answer (score 4):

Check out [Symmetric algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_algebra), it looks like it's exactly what you're looking for.